# Different types of logs which contain Useragent strings?

Tags: regex, user-agent

I want to make a userAgent parser for different types of logs. We did it for APACHE, NCSA, IIS, W3C. What other logs generate Useragent strings?

Answer (score 0):

User-agents are identifiers by which clients of the http protocol identify themselves. These identifications can be read by any http server, so it looks like you will want to cover all of those.

Here are a few ones you haven't mentioned : GlassFish, WebLogic Server, Wildfly, JBoss EAP, Tomcat, nginx. But there'll be a lot of others.